# What is the attribute for an Action to display only if it is called in another View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I cannot remember the attribute that allows only an action to be rendered if it is called within a view (e.g. @Html.Action()). Can anyone refresh my memory? I do not want the action to be able to be called directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult SomeAction()
```

More info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.childactiononlyattribute.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking to render a Partial View

```
@Html.Partial("MyPartial")
```